# How to get a list of matchable characters from a regex class

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

Given a regex character class/set, how can i get a list of all matchable characters (in python 3). E.g.:

```
[\dA-C]
```

should give

```
['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C']
```

Comment: I am not able to get your issue. Can you also provide sample input and required output with the question?

Comment: @anonymous sample input like `[\dA-C]` and sample output like `['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C']`? This question's too broad, but it's hardly unclear.

Comment: that's an interesting question. What is your goal ?

Comment: This is restricted to character classes, i.e. to single-character regexps, right? Can it be assumed that it will only match ascii?

Comment: @alexis single char but may be non-ascii

Comment: Then a complete solution will not be very practical. I I just write `[\w]`, the answer is most of the Unicode character set. If you can restrict your interest to particular codepoint ranges, then you can get somewhere.

Comment: isn't  \w only [0-9a-zA-Z_] ?

Comment: Not in the Unicode world-- try it with a Hebrew word! Neither is `\d` just `[0-9]`, see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I think what you are looking for is [`string.printable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.printable) which returns all the printable characters in Python. For example:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.printable
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
```

Now to check content satisfied by your regex, you may do:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = string.printable
>>> pattern = r'[\dA-C]'
>>> print(re.findall(pattern, x))
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

`string.printable` is a combination of *digits, letters, punctuation,* and *whitespace*. Also check [String Constants](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-constants) for complete list of constants available with [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module.

---

*In case you need the list of all `unicode` characters*, you may do:

```
import sys
unicode_list = [chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode)]
```

**Note:** It will be a huge list, and console might get stuck for a while to give the result as value of `sys.maxunicode` is:

```
>>> sys.maxunicode
1114111
```

In case you are dealing with some specific unicode formats, refer [Unicode Character Ranges](http://billposer.org/Linguistics/Computation/UnicodeRanges.html) for limiting the ranges you are interested in.

Comment: That's a nice solution as long as the only thing we care about is ascii-- otherwise it falls down on `[é]`.

Comment: i need also unicode chars such as hebrew letters, nbsp, etc.

Comment: guess i will do with: x = ''.join([chr(i) for i in range(2000)])

Comment: @eyaler: Updated the answer to return the list of all unicode characters, but  please also read the note part

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

x = '123456789ABCDE'
pattern = r'[\dA-C]'
print(re.findall(pattern,x))    
#prints ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

Is this what you are looking for?

If you don't have `x` and just want to match ascii characters you can use :

```
import re
import string

x = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
pattern = r'[\dA-C]'
print(re.findall(pattern,x))
```

If you want to take inputs for the pattern you can simply just do:

```
 pattern = input() #with either one from above
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably hoped to just extract them from the regexp itself, but it's not that easy: Consider specifications like `\S`, which doesn't match a contiguous range of characters, negated specifications like `[^abc\d]`, and of course goodies like `(?![aeiou])\w` (which matches any single letter *except* the five vowels given). So it's far simpler to just try out each candidate character against your regexp.

But checking all Unicode codepoints is not very practical, both because of the large number of tests and because the result could be a very large list: A character class regexp might contain specifications like `\w`,
which can match an enormous number of characters from all over the Unicode table. Or it could contain a negated specification like `[^abc\d]`,
which matches even more.  So let's assume that you can restrict your interest to a particular
subset of the
Unicode range. After consulting a [table of Unicode ranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block#collapsibleTable0),
you might decide, for the sake of example, that you are interested in the ranges [0000-024F]
(Basic and Extended Latin) and [0590-074F] (Hebrew and Arabic).

You can then churn through each of these unicode codepoints,
checking which ones are matched by your regexp:

```
import re

myregexp = r"[\dA-C]"
interest = [ (0x0000, 0x024F),
             (0x0590, 0x06FF) ]


pattern = re.compile(myregexp)
matched = []    
for low, high in interest:
    matched.extend(chr(p) for p in range(low, high+1) if pattern.match(chr(p)))

>>> print("".join(matched))
0123456789ABC٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹
```